# Unable to Connect to BigQuery from local App Engine instance in Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm new to Google App Engine and I'm trying to run through some of the tutorials to see how this would work for my organization.  We are looking at putting some of our data into BigQuery and converting some of our Web applications to App Engine which would need to access BigQuery data.

I am using the java-docs-samples-master code, specifically bigquery/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/SimpleApp.java

I can run this from the command line using

> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.bigquery.SimpleAppMain

I incorporate the code into App Engine, which I'm running in Eclipse and created a wrapper so I could still run it from the command line.  It works when running from the command line but I get an error when I run it from App Engine in Eclipse.

Is there something I'm missing to configure my local App Engine to connect to Big Query?

Error:

```
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Invalid project ID 'no_app_id'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:86)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:170)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$3.call(BigQueryImpl.java:208)
...
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
{ "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid project ID 'no_app_id'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid project ID 'no_app_id'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash."
}
```

Code:

```
package com.example.bigquery;

import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldValue;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryResponse;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryResult;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class SimpleApp {
  public void runBQ() throws Exception {
    // [START create_client]
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    // [END create_client]
    // [START run_query]
    QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
        QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                "SELECT "
                    + "APPROX_TOP_COUNT(corpus, 10) as title, "
                    + "COUNT(*) as unique_words "
                    + "FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`;")
            // Use standard SQL syntax for queries.
            // See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/
            .setUseLegacySql(false)
            .build();

    // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
    JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

    // Wait for the query to complete.
    queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

    // Check for errors
    if (queryJob == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
    } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
      // You can also look at queryJob.getStatus().getExecutionErrors() for all
      // errors, not just the latest one.
      throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
    }

    // Get the results.
    QueryResponse response = bigquery.getQueryResults(jobId);
    // [END run_query]

    // [START print_results]
    QueryResult result = response.getResult();

    // Print all pages of the results.
    while (result != null) {
      for (List<FieldValue> row : result.iterateAll()) {
        List<FieldValue> titles = row.get(0).getRepeatedValue();
        System.out.println("titles:");

        for (FieldValue titleValue : titles) {
          List<FieldValue> titleRecord = titleValue.getRecordValue();
          String title = titleRecord.get(0).getStringValue();
          long uniqueWords = titleRecord.get(1).getLongValue();
          System.out.printf("\t%s: %d\n", title, uniqueWords);
        }

        long uniqueWords = row.get(1).getLongValue();
        System.out.printf("total unique words: %d\n", uniqueWords);
      }

      result = result.getNextPage();
    }
    // [END print_results]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your error code, it's probably due to your project ID not being set: "no_app_id". Here is how to set your project ID for app engine: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_appid_version.

Comment: I looked at the link you provided, I don't have a google menu option when I right click on the project.  
FYI - I have the "Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 4.5 and later" plugin installed.  From what I can see there is an older "Google Plugin for Eclipse", but that wants to uninstall the other plugin I have installed.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Can you see if it exists in the file: "The project ID and version for a particular App Engine project are defined by the appengine-web.xml file, found in the war/WEB-INF directory"?

Comment: I don't have either of them listed in the appengine-web.xml.  I looked up the format and added <application> and <version> tags and it gives me a warning that "Project ID should be specified at deploy time"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am late, but I encountered such error while working with Firestore and it was due to no project being set on the 'Cloud Platform' tab in App Engine run configuration. When I logged into an account and selected a project ID, this error went away.